# Writing executable program.exe to read and write files in but in this manner program.exe<input.txt>output.txt

Tags: c++

First off, its not a homework problem. I know how to read and write files,parse lines in C++ if I already know the name of the files involved but I need to run the same code for different file names both input and output, and it will be called numerous times. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void file_reader(ifstream &file_read, ofstream &file_out){}
int main(){
ifstream file_read("temp.lmps",ios::in);
ofstream file_out("data.lmps",ios::out);
file_reader(file_read,file_out);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Change

```
void file_reader(ifstream &file_read, ofstream &file_out){}
```

to use `istream` and `ostream` instead of `ifstream` and `ofstream`.

Then, call it with `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

```
void file_reader(std:istream& in_stream, std::ostream& out_stream){}

int main()
{
   file_reader(std::cin, std::cout);
   return 0;
}
```

Now you can use

```
program.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

**Option 2**

Pass the input file and the output file as arguments to the program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::ifstream file_read(argv[1],ios::in);
   std::ofstream file_out(argv[2],ios::out);
   file_reader(file_read, file_out);
   return 0;
}
```

Now you can use

```
program.exe input.txt output.txt
```